# Mage::helper('catalog/category'); not displaying all categories

Tags: category, helper

This was already asked in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22637664/magento-magehelpercatalog-category) but didn't get a correct response.

I also did the two answers in the previous thread.

I need `Mage::helper('catalog/category');` to display all categories, not just those that have "Include in Navigation Menu" checked.

Comment: Try `Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()`

Comment: Like the previous thread. I also need to use Mage::helper because using what you said returns nothing.

Answer (score 1):

> I also need to use `Mage::helper` because using what you said returns nothing

You need to use `Mage::helper`, because this returns nothing? This argument is wrong :-)

Get a collection of the categories, filter them if you want:

```
$categories = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category');
foreach($categories as $cat) {
    echo $cat->getName();
}
```

If this return nothing, please tell me, what you are doing.

Comment: To be honest. I'm not sure why. All I know is that `Mage::helper('catalog/category')->getStoreCategories()` only returns those that are included in the menu. Are there any function other than `getStoreCategories()` that gets all?

Comment: yes, a generic collection without any filter, like the one I wrote in the answer. and KennyDs already mentioned ;)

Answer (score 1):

try
Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')

Answer (score 0):

```
$helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category');

// sorted by name, fetched as collection
$categoriesCollection = $helper->getStoreCategories('name', true, false);

// sorted by name, fetched as array
$categoriesArray = $helper->getStoreCategories('name', false, false);
```

Via model:

```
 $_categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

Comment: Don't use * if it is not needed!

Comment: Yep right, corrected now